# Using parameterized queries to retrieve the matching table rows by clicking radio buttons and displaying them in a DataGridView Control

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am creating a program that uses a table of karate members from a database that allows the user to select a date from a DateTimePicker control. The program displays the first name, last name, phone #'s and dates joined of all members who joined before the selected date. I need to use a a parameterized query to retrieve the matching table rows and display them in a DataGridView Control. After that, I need add radio button that allows the user to choose before this date or on or after this date.

So far, I created the DateTimePicker control from Dates_Joined in the members data set and included the data grid view. I then added two radio buttons from the Dates_Joined in the members data set, and tried creating a query for each. It is not working properly for getting the filtered rows after specifying the date from the picker and then clicking on either the before or on or after this date radio button.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'KarateDataSet.Members' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.MembersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.KarateDataSet.Members)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BeforeToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BeforeToolStripButton.Click
        Try
            Me.MembersTableAdapter.Before(Me.KarateDataSet.Members, New System.Nullable(Of Date)(CType(Date_JoinedToolStripTextBox.Text, Date)))
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FillByToolStripButton.Click
        Try
            Me.MembersTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.KarateDataSet.Members, New System.Nullable(Of Date)(CType(Date_JoinedToolStripTextBox1.Text, Date)))
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Firstly, you should not have a method named `FillBy`.  The idea is that you specify the filter(s) in the method name. You want to be able to query in three different ways so you should add three queries to your table adapter. They each filter by `Dates_Joined` but each in a different way, i.e. `Dates_Joined < ?`, `Dates_Joined = ?` and `Dates_Joined > ?`. The methods should be named `FillByBeforeDatesJoined`, `FillByOnDatesJoined` and `FillByAfterDatesJoined` or the like. You then call whichever method is appropriate at the time.

Comment: That said, it appears that you're actually calling `Fill` when the form loads and thus getting all the data upfront. If that's the case then there's no point querying again to get data you already have.  You should just filter the data you have by setting the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` bound to the grid.

Comment: Also, you say that you are using a `DateTimePicker` and yet your code is actually using a `ToolStringTextBox`. What's up with that?